# Why is the position not changing? And, How do I make it change?

Tags: jquery, positioning

I have a calendar page that I'm trying to position events on.  Unlike most javascript calendars that you see (google calendar, etc.) there is dynamic content above the calendar that fluctuates in size based on ajax calls.  So, I need a function that I can call to position the events on the calendar when the page size changes.  For my first step, I am drawing some static divs on a page, and then trying to position them on the calendar on page load.  The events should float above the calendar, with the top of the event lining up to the calendar cell that it floats over.

I have the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrEEA/
The code is here as well since JSFiddle died: http://midas.sleepex.com/calendar.html

When I inspect the divs in chrome after running the script, it says the top and left coordinates are correct, but the divs are not positioned over the calendar.  What am I doing wrong and how do I make this work?

Comment: Fiddle seems to be having issues right now, but usually if the coordinates for something are "correct", but the element shows up in the wrong place, you've got incorrect positioning settings and the relative coordinates are going "relative" to something other than what you expect. Instead of positioning, how about using DOM injection so your events just become a child element of the appropriate day's container element?

Comment: Thanks, Marc.  I suspect it's true, but I can't quite get it right.  Here's the code elsewhere:  http://midas.sleepex.com/calendar.html

Comment: Ah, regarding the child element, that won't work because the calendar events need to float over several hours, depending on how long the event is.

Comment: I did get part of fiddle to load, and you're using `position: absolute`.  Unless you've got some other parent element of your events listed as `position:relative`, that means your events are being positioned relative to the top/left of the whole document. Try wrapping the calendar in a plain div that's position:relative, and insert your events into that div so that they position absolutely on the div, not the document.

Comment: Bingo.  http://midas.sleepex.com/calendar.html  Marc, can you change your last response to an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `position: absolute`. Unless you've got some other parent element of your events listed as position:relative, that means your events are being positioned relative to the top/left of the whole document. Try wrapping the calendar in a plain div that's `position:relative`, and insert your events into that div so that they position absolutely on the div, not the document.